# Autowiring a filtered list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired, spring-java-config

I have multiple implementations (ComponentA, ComponentB, ComponentC) of an interface (Component) which needs to be autowired to a configuration class (MyConfiguration) depending on a property provided by a properties file.

MyConfiguration class;

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:settings.properties")
public class MyConfiguration implements ConfigurationService {

@Value("#{'${enabled.components}'.split(',')}")
private Set<String> enabledComponentQualifiers;

@Autowired
private Set<Component> enabledComponentSet;
...
```

ComponentA class (ComponentB, ComponentC have the same structure);

```
@Component("componenta")
public class ComponentA implements Component {
...
```

settings.property file;

```
enabled.components=componenta,componentb
```

I'd like to have the autowired set (enabledComponentSet above) to include only the components filtered in enabled.components property.

What's the best way to do that using JavaConfig?

Comment: In your example above, you only want to inject ComponentA and ComponentB into the Set. In that case, is it still important that ComponentC even be instantiated? If not, then you could use a conditional to prevent unwanted Component implementations from being created and then the wiring of Component beans into the Set is just a matter of injecting all available Component beans.

Comment: It's ok (and desired) not to instantiate excluded components since they are not required throughout the life-cycle of the application. Thus I agree with your suggestion. I'll give it a try and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Setting `@ConditionalOnExpression("'${enabled.components}'.contains('componenta')")` in Component implementations did the trick however I'm forced to include the _enabled.components=componenta,componentb_ property inside of the application.properties file. Even though Configuration class has `@PropertySource("classpath:settings.properties")`, seems like it's not available during condition evaluation. Any ideas how to get _settings.properties_ effective @CraigWalls?

Comment: I just tried it, recreating your setup (as closely as I can without seeing your full project source) and it worked fine for me. In short, I had Initializr give me a starting point with Spring MVC and Actuator. I created a settings.properties with `enabled.components` in it as you describe. I created `ComponentA` class annotated with `@Component` and the same `@ConditionalOnExpression` you have. I also added some sysouts to `ComponentA` constructor so I could see it getting created at startup. Finally, I annotated the bootstrap class with `@PropertySource`. I ran it and it worked.

Comment: Indeed, `@PropertySource` is one of the property sources considered by Spring Boot's special property source (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html), so I see no reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: The trick is in your last sentence; "_Finally, I annotated the **bootstrap class** with `@PropertySource`._" In my question `@PropertySource` was on the `@Configuration` class. It seems to be the reason whether `settings.properties` is not available. Moving that annotation to my project's **bootstrap class** solved the problem. Although it got solved, I'm not happy being forced to include component specific properties on the bootstrap class instead of the Configuration class whose the main class managing these components.

Comment: Small side note; @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987333/propertysource-not-available-during-conditionalonexpression-evaluation