# PropertySource not available during ConditionalOnExpression evaluation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-java-config

I have this following component class which I'd like to instantiate depending on a property;

```
@Component("componentA")
@PropertySource("classpath:components.properties")
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${components.enabled}'.contains('componentA')")
public class ComponentA implements ComponentIF {
...
```

components.properties file has the following property;

```
components.enabled=componentA,componentB,componentD
```

The problem is that `@PropertySource("classpath:components.properties")` seems to be not available during the evaluation of `@ConditionalOnExpression("'${components.enabled}'.contains('componentA')")`.

On the other hand, if I put the `components.enabled=componentA,componentB,componentD` property inside of the spring-boot's `application.properties` file, the property becomes available during ConditionalOnExpression evaluation and it's working as expected.

However, I'd like to use `components.properties` in order to keep the all component specific properties in the same place.

Any ideas whether PropertySource is not effective during ConditionalOnExpression?

Comment: Because those are loaded later in the proces, when all `@Configuration` are determined, those are scanned. The `application.properties` is loaded very early in the startup proces and hence all of those are available. If you want them to be available don't use `@PropertySource` but use an `ApplicationContextInitializer` to add a property source.

Comment: I moved the `@PropertySource("classpath:components.properties")` anootation to my project's **bootstrap class** so that it's now available during the valuation of ConditionalOnExpression.

Comment: Hope the answer solves your issue. If so do upvote it and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

[I also had the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54519104/6663095). In my case, I wanted to enable certain Aspects based on condition. It seems that spring reads some values during the earlier stages of initialization and it's difficult to override those values. (like values of `@ConditionalOnExpression`).

In order to set the values of these variables.

1. Specify the property in `application.properties` in your classpath. The variables loaded at the earlier stages are always read from this file.
2. Use profiles and define `application.properties` as `application-profile.properties` and activate the respective profile.
3. Pass the property value as a JVM parameter like `-Dproperty.key=value`.

Else If you wanted to override the property using property files itself I would advise you to [go through this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54722355/6663095).

***All these can be combined all together. [To know about their precedence refer this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config).***