# Spring boot properties to be loaded at initialization and respect all and control @Aspect based on the value from property file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, properties-file

We are loading properties from an external file using `@PropertySources`. Now I want to enable/disable `@Aspect` based on a property. I tried using `@ConditionalOnExpression` which didn't work. I tried the same by creating a bean of `propertyplaceholderconfig`. Even in the same case, it didn't work. Then I tried `@profile` which also didn't work initially.

What I Figured out is that these variables are not initialized at the starting when `propertysource` or `propertyplaceholder` bean is used at startup. Some variables are always ignored like (logging.file). But `@Value` works fine. In order to set these variables, I've to pass them as JVM parameters.

**So my questions are:

1. How can I make spring to always read specified property files at startup and respect all of them?

2. Which is the best way to enable/disable `@Aspect`. Using `@profile` or `@ConditionalOnExpression` or something else?**

Currently, we are setting `logging.file` in the main method since this also behaves the same way. But you guys know that it's not the proper way as I may end up adding the properties one by one like this. I want to put all the properties into external files such that spring reads those files and sets its properties.

Our properties structure:

1. common.properties #This has all common properties
2. service.properties #Property specific to a service. This will also contain existing property from common.properties which will be overridden.

I understand that I can use profiles. But, we want to keep the properties outside such you need to restart service if you are changing the properties. I also don't want to pass the variables as JVM parameters then I've to pass most of the variables in this way. Passing -Dspring.config.location is also difficult as `common.properties` and `service.properties` are used and 'service.properties' filename varies for each service.

sample codes:

Mainclass:

```
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource(value = "file:${property_path}/common.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = false),
        @PropertySource(value = "file:${property_path}/service1.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true) })
public class MainClass {
static String logDirectory = ApplicationContext.getGlobalProperty("logging.file");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(MainClass.class);

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("logging.file", logDirectory);
        springApplication.setDefaultProperties(properties);
        springApplication.run(args);
    }
}
```

Application Context:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ApplicationContext implements EnvironmentAware {

    private static Environment environment;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        ApplicationContext.environment = environment;
    }
    public static String getGlobalProperty(String propertyName) {
    return environment.getProperty(propertyName);
    }
}
```

Here you can see any way I've used `environment` to get `property`. Is there any way to set the property using the environment such that while spring boot initialization itself the properties are populated?

We can also implement `ApplicationContextInitializer` and override `initialize` method to read properties. But how can I make it read 2 property files and override the duplicate property with the latest value? [Reference(I'm not sure how to implement my requirements in this way.)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34987333/6663095). Even in this case doesn't sound like you are trying to kill a mosquito with a hammer?

Current working Solution:

```
@Aspect
@Profile("!production")
@Configuration
public class ControllerAspect {
@pointcut(....)
} //Here also I've to pass spring.profiles.active as JVM params.
//setting the value in common.properties or service1.properties is not working.
```

I'm a newbie to spring boot so please let me know for additional clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Spring by default loads some properties at initialization and unless until you specifically write logic to overwrite them ***(like the one I wrote in `MainClass.java`)*** there is no option to override those. Some of these include (logging.file, key used in @ConditionalonExpression).

#### Some tricks with their own challenges:

1. Specify the properties in `application.properties` in your classpath. The variables loaded at the earlier stages are always read from this file. **challenge: I've tight coupled all my properties into the jar and in order to change the values I've to recompile and relaunch the Jar.**
2. Use profiles and define `application.properties` as `application-profile.properties`. ***challenge: I've to create so many profiles and still the previous challenge exists.***
3. Pass the property value as JVM parameter as `-Dproperty.key=value`. ***challenge:seriously? How many properties am I supposed to send as JVM parameter?***
4. Implement `ApplicationContextInitialize` and override `initialize` method.***challenge:Overriding Spring's default behaviour is not recommended as well as isn't it an overkill to use this just for reading property file?***

#### Solution:

Use `-Dspring.config.location` to specify the property files. In this case, always spring reads the properties only from the specified location(s). You can provide multiple property files as well. **[Refer this for much more details.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)** It seems if you give property locations as Directories spring loads them in reverse order. But if you specify files it follows the order specified.

**Note: All these can be combined together. [To know about precedence refer this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config).**